# How to resolve the "undefined variable" notce when I put a flag on a Views page?

Tags: flags, views

I want to place a flag link on a page, as suggested on that page: https://www.drupal.org/node/295383

The flag will subscribe the user to the most recent content page, which is done in Views.

I have the Flags: subscribe (by current user) Relationship.

I have installed Views PHP and I want to add to the header of the view a Global:PHP with the code `<?php print flag_create_link('subscribe', $node->nid); ?>`

Unfortunately I receive an error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: node in __lambda_func() (line 1 of .../sites/all/modules/views_php/plugins/views/views_php_handler_area.inc(39) : runtime-created function).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in __lambda_func() (line 1 of .../sites/all/modules/views_php/plugins/views/views_php_handler_area.inc(39) : runtime-created function).

What could be the reason for that?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, OOB it won't work because Flags require an entity to function, but Views pages are simple menu callbacks, not actual entities (such as nodes, users, comments, etc). So, in order to do this, you would need to trick it into think it is an entity:

- create a content type, `Dummy Page` for this example
- remove the body and restrict editing, deleting, etc to admin only
- Create a node with this content, using the title you want for the View, `Recent Content` for this example, give it a path alias `/recent`
- create the view as a block, and in the block UI, set it to show only on the `recent` page
- Create a flag for Nodes, `Favourites`
- create a page--recent.tpl.php file and override the `$action_link` for the page (or modify it drastically however you want), but include:

`<?php print flag_create_link('favourites', $node->nid); ?>`

Or use the built in flag link that comes with the Flag

- then do whatever you were going to do originally with the flag. You can include it in other Views pages by creating new nodes of that content type and include the View as a block, etc.

This will trick the Flag into thinking the page is an entity and track it properly, as well as display it on the page wherever you decide to put it

Comment: Hi Geoff thank for your answer. Actually I want to put this in the Header of the View, not per item in the view.

Comment: @peer see my edit...

Comment: Hi Geoff thank you for your update. Your suggestion prints the flag as supposed. The problem is that the flag is not working on the page /recent - I've tried both with my custom flag "Subscribe" and with the default flag "Bookmark". When I put both flags on another node page it works as expected...

Comment: I just ran a test and it works fine for me - you say it's not working, what isn't working?

Comment: Hi Geoff. The idea is: The page "Recent content" has a flag "Subscribe" which sends an email to the user each time there is something new (new comments for example, or new content on the site). When user flags "Subscribe" emails are being send. I can flag the page al right. Bit there are no emails. Now, to crosscheck the flag, I've put it on a different content type, flag from another node, and in that case receive emails. I've tried with my "Subscribe" flag and with the default "Bookmark this" flag.

Comment: well, the View is irrelevant to the content, just a block associated - so what is on the content type that works, that is missing on the content type that doesn't?  Something is different, and that difference is causing this new issue. Also, how are you sending the email?

Comment: If you mean to send an email when the content on the View changes, that won't work - you will have to write something completely custom I think

Comment: I send the email through Rules and the rule is not activated by a change on the actual page "Recent content", but from general events like "After saving a new comment" or "After saving new content". The node on which is the flag "Subscribe" doesn't matter, its only that in my opinion the most logical place to subscribe to new content email notification is on the page listing new content - "Recent content". Thats why I find it strange that when flagged from "Recent content" the rule is not activated, but when flagged from another page it works fine...

Comment: Ok. I assume there is a condition in the rule that the flag be set for the content?

Comment: No, I don't have conditions on the rule. I will create some test users and will investigate this deeper, as it seems it is a Rules issue now.

Comment: If I now understand what you are trying to do, I think it might not be a rules issue, I think it might be a design issue - you want people to follow content? so that when it changes or comments are created, they are notified? If there's no condition on the rule, what is the point of the flag? do you email every user on every content being updated?

Comment: Hi, Geoff, thanks for the reply. Yes, I have few users and I want to email all subscribers changes to the same content.

Comment: then what is the point of the flag?

Comment: Hmm, so how do I do it than? What would be the most suitable way to have a "Subscribe" button on one page only - the "Recent content" page, and when users activate/deactivate the "Subscribe" button they start/stop receiving notifications?

Comment: it's really up to you - if it's an all or nothing deal and its user specific, then I would do it as part of their user profile as a personal setting, just using a boolean field value rather than flags. Then add a condition to the Rules that the boolean be set for each user before sending the update email

Comment: Hi Geoff, I followed your advice, but cannot configure the Condition..

I have a test action "User has logged in/out" and as condition Data value is empty on site:current-user:field-subscription which is negated. The action is "Send mail to all users of a role"

But it is sending the email to all with the same role with or without the boolean ticked.

Answer (score 0):

The error arises because there is no $node variable defined in the scope.
Try looking inside the $results variable; something like this should work:

```
<?php print flag_create_link('subscribe', $results[0]->nid); ?>
```

This will print a subscribe link for the first row of the view. 
Also, you have to ensure that the nid is present in your result object. It should be already there, but if not, add the "Content: Nid" field and hide it by checking the "Exclude from display" option.

Comment: Hi, peterpoe, thanks for your reply. Your code is not printing anything. In the Global/PHP i have the following available variables $view: The view object. $handler: The handler object. $results: Array containing the view's result.

Comment: Hi, peterpoe, this did the trick, but it was a problem on my side, I have previously limited the flag to Panels only. Now its working ok. Thanks.

Comment: Now I encounter the problem that the content of the view changes because it is a Recent content - view of new or updated content. And when the first raw changes the flag is not activated.

Comment: Now I get it: I think you might have misunderstood the use of Flags. You can't flag a view, you can only flag entities, which may or may not be listed as results of a view. What is the intended effect of subscribing "the user to the most recent content page"?

Comment: Hi, peterpoe, check the discussion under Geoff's reply.